# Run different python files on Django startup

Tags: python, django

After running my Django project, I want my different python files to run concurrently until I terminate the project. When I run "python manage.py runserver" I want different python files to run at the same time. Is there a way to do this in django? I searched but couldn't find the exact result I wanted.

Comment: What do you mean by run concurrently?

Comment: Maybe `python manage.py shell` is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Vusal As long as my django website is running, I want my .py files to do some processing in the background.

Comment: @Bartosz Stasiak I tried "python manage.py shell", unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: Why? We still don't know what do you want to do exactly

Comment: @Bartosz Stasiak I am doing web based server security. Python code that performs live protection operations while django is running needs to run.